# Live Connect API Windows 8 app file source URL changing

Tags: windows-8, liveconnect

I have an app that syncs data through a JSON file hosted on the users SkyDrive. I'm storing the URL to the file after it is created in the users Roam Settings, but it seems to change at some point and I can figure out what's going on. Do source URL's change randomly? When the file is overwritten perhaps?

Comment: The answer is yes! Every time you overwrite the file the source URL changes. Ugh! That would be a nice thing to mention in the documentation...

Comment: This really makes syncing data a nightmare. There is no easy way to do this between devices with Live Connect. It seems clean and simple, but a request to get a folder/file takes forever. An ajax request with the source URL takes a fraction of a second...but, if the source URL is always changing, there's another challenge to deal with.